# Show/hide elements in a single line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a function with an ID. This ID should be used to `.show()` the element(s) matched the selector and `.hide()` everything didn't.

```
function showAndHide(id){
    $('.container div').hide();
    $('.container div[data-id="'+id+'"]').show();
}
```

Is there a smarter way then this? I wanna avoid writing the part of the selector twice (`.container div`) and get a more clearly notation.

Comment: I think this way is just fine.

Comment: If you want to do something "cooler" you should try another Framework, jQuery is overweight for this purpose. But if you have a large codebase in jQuery this is the best solution.

Comment: If you want, you'd rewrite it in one line: 
$('.container div').hide('fast',function(){if($(this).data('id') == id ) $(this).show();});
But your code is good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use chaining & [filtering](http://jqapi.com/#p=filter):

```
$('.container div').hide().filter('[data-id="'+id+'"]').show();
```

The first selector selects all child divs in `.container`, so hide acts on all of those.
The filter takes a subset of the first set based on the second selector (similar to `.find()` which acts on child elements). So the final `show()` is only acting on the filtered element.

Answer (score 2):

A **faster** alternative to using `filter()` is to use **[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**:

```
$('.container div').not('[data-id="'+ id +'"]').hide();
```

This way you've never having to actually use `show()` as you're never actually hiding it (less methods, improved speed, no unnecessary hiding/showing).

[**jsPerf here**](http://jsperf.com/test102034) - it is much faster in all browsers, and double as fast as `filter()` in `IE8/9`.

Comment: Why not just select only the visible? `$('.container div:visible').hide()`

Comment: @Bondye :visible is *extremely* slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.

```
$('.container div, .container div[data-id="'+id+'"]').toggle();
```

Comment: @MarcelBöttcher What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/XhjNs/

```
function showAndHide(id){
$('.container div').not('[data-id="'+id+'"]').hide();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're a lot of "ways" to update your function.

You should check this [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/5cDvz/) made using the `console.profile();` and `console.profileEnd();` a really helpful Javascript methods (native).

The solution posted by @MorganTyle seems to be the best in term of calling and performance overall so you should follow him.

You can found an article about profiling [Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-jquery-beginners-can-test-and-improve-their-code/)

Answer (score -2):

Something like this is maybe what you are looking for:

```
function showAndHide(id){
    $('.container div').each(function () {
        var t = $(this);
        if(t.data("id") == id) {
            t.show();
        } 
        else { 
            t.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He is trying to keep it simple

Comment: My understanding is he didn't want to `.show()` or `.hide()` elements that didn't need it.